# Alternatives to LVM

Tags: lvm, raid

I was thinking about alternatives to combine several HDDs together.

The only options I know so far are using LVM and/or RAID.
The thing is, using LVM, I will most probably lose all data, if one volume in my volume group fail. Using RAID, however, is (for my purposes) a waste of space.

So basically I am looking for a way to combine HDDs together, where I can remove and add more later on, but will not lose data from the other combined drive, if one disk fails.

I just heard about `mhddfs`. Is that a reliable method to combine disks?

Comment: With LVM, you *don't* lose data except what is on the failed drives by default.  This is because by default, the allocation policy is linear, aka JBOD in raid terms.  You only lose everything when one drive fails with raid0.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS)?

It sounds like it would do **exactly** what you are looking for. And because, sometime a video is better than a wikipedia link: check-out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGIwg6ye1gE)

Comment: Good video indeed. I haven't heard much about `ZFS`, but IIRC you always have to run the zpools in a RAID similar system?

Comment: ZFS doesn't answer the question. If you lose a disk in a raid0 configuration, you lose all the data just like any other stipped raid0.

Comment: Do you have a current link for that youtube video or a title to search on? I'd be interested in that.

Comment: @BeachBum68 not sure if this is absolutely the same video, but I guess it's close to it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN6iDzesEs0